# Improve performance javax.persistence transactions to remote database

Tags: mysql, database, performance, jpa, eclipselink

When developing the application against my local database there were no problems with the speed of transactions, although the CPU usage was constantly at about 30 percents when performing several transactions per second, and when profiling most of the time was spent in javax methods handling the transactions with an average of 2.6 seconds per transaction. Therefore I'm using an ArrayList as a buffer and only sending the transaction when the size of the buffer exceeds 300 instances, which significantly lowered the CPU usage.

When I'm changing my persistence.xml to use a remote database instead (checked both RDS and a personal, off-site database) the minimum time for persisting/committing a batch of instances is about 20 seconds, which is too high since a transaction of 300 instances is required once every 5 seconds (on average).

I've tried to change the flushmode of the EntityManager to `FlushModeType.COMMIT` but it didn't change the performance noticeably. Increasing the size of the buffer before sending causes a stack overflow with the javax.persistence library for some (to me) unknown reason.

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="PU-data" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    ... // class, shared-cache-mode=none, validation-mode=none ...
    <properties>
        ... // Authentication ...
        <!-- Optimization attempts -->
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="300" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true" /> 
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="commit" />
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.persist-on-commit" value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**Facade handling the transactions**

```
MouseFacade.bufferSemaphore.acquireUninterruptibly(1);
if (MouseFacade.buffer.size() >= 300) {
    EntityManager entityManager = EMF.getEntityManager();
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        for (Mouse mouse : MouseFacade.buffer) {
            entityManager.persist(mouse);
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

        entityManager.close();
        MouseFacade.buffer.clear();
    }

}
MouseFacade.bufferSemaphore.release(1);
```

**ORM mapping**

```
<entity-mappings version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <entity class="se.my.package.Mouse">
        <table-generator name="ORD_SEQ" allocation-size="300"/>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

---

**Update**

I've gone through the suggestions found at this page, called *How to improve JPA performance by 1,825%* (http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.se/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html), but there is no difference what so ever which makes me wonder whether I'm missing a key point about batch writing and MySQL. I've rewritten the entities not to rely on relationships and minimized my read-operations to 1 for the entire application in order to just focus on the write problems.

When looking through the EclipseLink log it doesn't look like batch-writing is being used at all, but instead 2 log entires are written for every instance which seems about right (300 instances * 2 connections * 24 latency = 14.4 seconds).

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-03-31 01:35:29.249--ClientSession(1213059092)--Connection(662811604)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-03-31 01:35:29.274--ClientSession(1213059092)--Connection(662811604)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--INSERT INTO mouse (event, posX, posY, created, uid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [12, 241, 250, 1364690113727, 1]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-03-31 01:35:29.298--ClientSession(1213059092)--Connection(662811604)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-03-31 01:35:29.323--ClientSession(1213059092)--Connection(662811604)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--INSERT INTO mouse (event, posX, posY, created, uid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [12, 233, 296, 1364690113443, 1]
...
```

**Progress**

By changing to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)` and `allocationSize=300` I've managed to reduce the number of requests by 50%, although it looks as if bind are still sent on their own when checking the EclipseLink log, even though batch writing is supposedly enabled.

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-03-31 01:35:29.323--ClientSession(1213059092)--Connection(662811604)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--INSERT INTO mouse (event, posX, posY, created, uid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
bind => [..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
```

Comment: Having high interactivity with an offsite database is challenging, the jdbc batch writing mentioned by David Levesque below is a good idea, but it's a fundamentally challenging paradigm.  Anyway you can restructure your system architecture to have a low latency connection to DB?  (e.g. 1-hop gigabit ethernet connection?)

Comment: No, the application is meant to collect usage information from everyday use of the mouse as a biometric study outside of a lab environment. The connection could be wired, wireless or over 3G for all I know. The alternative would be to write everything to file and ask the users in the study to send those in manually, which I really hope to avoid since analysis needs to be performed as the data comes in.

Comment: @Taylor Although I can't really see how the amount of data I'm sending could result in this kind of performance hit. 7 int(16) per instance and 300 instances at a time should amount to something like 33kB of data. Using a 10Mbit upstream connection it should take about 30 ms to send the raw data which would mean that the database overhead is **huge**?

Comment: it's much more about latency (i.e. the loopback or "ping" time) than bandwidth.  The challenge your facing is the overhead of negotiation, which involves a few "back and forth"'s, each one of those incurs the loopback time.  Batching will help a lot, you may also want to consider connection pooling.

Comment: Focusing on latency rather than the amount of data being sent was a great advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sequencing to use table sequencing allowing sequence numbers to be preallocated.  What you have now forces each insert into its own statement so that the id can be found right after - which prevents batching.  Table and other strategies allowing preallocation will give better performance if matched up with the size of your batches.  Optimization #6 in http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.se/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

Comment: Thanks! Changing this cuts the time required in half (about 7.5 seconds), but looking at the EL logs it still looks like every bind statement is sent on its own, which is supported by calculating total latency [(300 + 1) * 24 ~= 7.2]. Would it be possible to send all those binds as a single request to the database, like bind;bind;bind;bind;...?

Comment: The log shows batch writing is sending everything to the driver as a single batch, the bind are just printed separately to the log so they are readable.  My guess is the MySQL driver has not be setup correctly for batching, see below.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling [JDBC batch writing](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_jdbc_batchwriting.htm). I'm not sure what difference it would make, but it may be worth trying.

Comment: Try using a connection pool such as c3p0 or apache dbcp, it looks like you're probably also having to negotiate a connection per txn or similar.

Comment: Re: connection pooling.  The pooling info was not shown in the persistence.xml, but EclipseLink defaults to using a connection pool of 32 connections, so this should not be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For batch writing in MySQL the MySQL JDBC driver does not batch statement unless you have set the following property in your conneciton URL,

```
?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

i.e.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```